# Configure vscode launch configuration to debug on cloud-run emulator using typescript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-debugging, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-code

I am trying to debug a google-cloud-run application on the cloud run emulator. The application is written in typescript. ZI can run and debug the application locally and it stop properly on breakpoints. However, when I try to debug on the cloud emulator it ignore or grays out my breakpoints.

I am trying this on vscode, the launch.json follows:

```
            "name": "Cloud Run: Run/Debug Locally",
            "type": "cloudcode.cloudrun",
            "request": "launch",
            "build": {
                "docker": {
                    "path": "Dockerfile"
                }
            },
            "image": "get-num-partitions",
            "service": {
                "name": "get-num-partitions",
                "containerPort": 8080,
                "resources": {
                    "limits": {
                        "memory": "256Mi"
                    }
                }
            },
            "target": {
                "minikube": {}
            },
            "watch": true,
            "debug": {}
        }
```

Again the application runs, and I can see the debugger attaching, it just wont respect breakpoints.

Comment: Google cloud has its own vscode plugin that allows debugging in the cloud-run emulator. Take a look at https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/vscode/install to see how to install and at https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/vscode/debugging-a-cloud-run-service to see how to debug the service in the emulator using the plugin.

Comment: I have cloud code installed, the issue is that source mapping is not working for local to containerized instance. The only other thing I can think off is to run the container from within vscode.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with what @Leuofirdia mentioned. There is separate extension offered by GCP called Cloud Code Plugin that does what you are looking for.

- [Cloud Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GoogleCloudTools.cloudcode) On Marketplace
- [Quick Start](https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/vscode/developing-a-cloud-run-service): Debug Cloud Run on Emulator
- Issues/Feature Request/Support - Use [Github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-code-vscode) Repo

Comment: I have cloud code installed, that is not the issue, the issue is that I cannot get typescript sourcemaps to work within cloud clode.

Comment: Thanks @GabrielJimenez. The source mapping is missing in the config based on the config you pasted above. When you choose "Debug on Cloud Run Emulator" at the end it will pop up to pick which process to debug (as a quick input) at the top, that would add below mapping to your launch configuration automatically.  Do you see the quick input?.                                                                                    ```  "debug": {
                "sourceFileMap": {
                    "${workspaceFolder}": "/usr/src/app"
                }
            } ```

Comment: tried this, no dice, could not get it working.